# Portenta H7 with Breakout Board, USB A as client and USB-C as Host

Tags: usb, vscode, arduino-portenta-h7

`Portenta H7` with Breakout Board. I would like to use the USB-A on Breakout Board as a client to send debug messages back to the terminal.
USB-C on the H7, I would like to use as a Host for Keyboards etc.

Is this possible?

If so does anyone have some example code because I have been going around in circles for a while now.